# How to extend objects without having to resort to typing them as <any>?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-editables

Suppose the following snippet of TypeScript:

```
class Item { 
    name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}

class Editor {
    items: KnockoutObservableArray<Item> = ko.observableArray([]);
    itemInEditMode: KnockoutObservable<Item> = ko.observable(null);

    constructor() {
        var x = new Item();
        this.items.push(x);
        this.itemInEditMode(x);
    }

    startEditing = (item: Item) => {
        ko.editables(item);  // <-- this extends `item` with methods, e.g. "rollback"
        this.itemInEditMode(item);
    }

    cancelEditing = () => {
        var item = this.itemInEditMode();
        this.itemInEditMode(null);
        item.rollback(); // <-- this causes a Typescript error
    }
}
```

In this example, the statement `ko.editables(item)` will extend the item and add a `rollback` method on it. How do I inform TypeScript of this change? Currently the above will create a problem with the TypeScript compiler on the `item.rollback()` statement, as an `Item` does not have a `rollback` method.

The most straightforward way to fix this would be to change one line to:

```
itemInEditMode: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable(null);
```

That is: use `any` so the `rollback` call is acceptable to the compiler. However, this will make you loose type checking and intellisense in many places.

Are there any alternatives? Could I perhaps change the first statement in `cancelEditing` so the `item` is treated as an `any`? Or could I perhaps write a custom `.d.ts` to solve this issue? I *am* using the [ko.editables.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout.editables/ko.editables.d.ts) file, perhaps I need a stronger version of that file?

Comment: When you extend a type with new methods, you effectively change the type. An `Item` with more methods is no longer just an item. I highly doubt that TS's type system is able to express that reasonably, though. In particular, the generated type should be inferred from the operations done, but TS type inference is also quite limited.

Comment: Aye, I understand. I was just hoping there was a TS feature I was missing, like an explicit cast to `any` (which I could use inside `cancelEditing`, so the rest of my code can use type safety). However, if it's not there, I guess an answer like "*Using `any` is the only option.*" could be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already have type information for the `editables` method - so you are just looking for how to extend your item with the editable extensions.

Step one is to create an interface that describes the extensions, if one doesn't already exist. Here is a really basic one:

```
interface KnockoutEditableExtensions {
    rollback(): void;
}
```

This is your re-usable "stuff that gets added" interface.

You can now use this to create a hybrid of any class...

```
interface ExtendedItem extends Item, KnockoutEditableExtensions {

}
```

It's a one liner that says `ExtendedItem` is the combination of `Item` and `KnockoutEditableExtensions`.

You can then do one small type assertion and get all the type information you need...

```
class Editor {
    items: KnockoutObservableArray<Item> = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Note the use of ExtendedItem type here...
    itemInEditMode: KnockoutObservable<ExtendedItem> = ko.observable(null);

    constructor() {
        var x = new Item();
        this.items.push(x);
    }

    startEditing = (item: Item) => {
        ko.editables(item);

        // Note the type assertion below...
        this.itemInEditMode(<ExtendedItem>item);
    }

    cancelEditing = () => {
        var item = this.itemInEditMode();
        this.itemInEditMode(null);
        item.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! This indeed looks like what I need. The `KnockoutEditableExtensions` you mention is in fact already inside [the `.d.ts` file mentioned in the question](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout.editables/ko.editables.d.ts), so that would work nicely. Will try this solution and will let you know if it worked for me.